# How can I Rename Home to something else in breadcrumbs Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Can someone help me replace "home" text in breadcrumbs?

I believe the change has to be made in breadcrumbs.html, but I am unfamiliar with the code.

I am using Cornerstone Light theme.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code for change text.

http://prntscr.com/qf1i7g

Open file from this path:

Components > Common > Breadcrumbs.html

And replace {{name}} with this code, Change your text that you want to show instead of "Home" at SHOP text placed in code:

```
{{#if name "==" "Home" }}SHOP{{else}}{{name}}{{/if}}
```